# Flux parallel operation and a blocking task post the parallel operation

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am new to reactive programming.I have a piece of code that should run parallel only once the parallel task is over code following it should be executed

```
 //step 1 parallel stuff
Flux.fromIterable( sourceOneMap.keySet() )
.parallel()
.runOn( Schedulers.parallel() )
.subscribe( compId -> {
 Mono.just( compId )
.then( checkIfSystemTwoContainsSystemOneInfo(compId,sourceOneMap,sourceTwoMap,new Timestamp( new Date().getTime() )) )
.doOnError( e -> log.info( "error {}",  e.getStackTrace()) );} );
 //step 2
 return new MissingCountResult( rtbmDao.findCount(), new Date() );
```

Now when i run my code step 2 is getting executed first and then step 1 .step 2 is dependent of step 1.Step 1 should compete first.Is there a way i can block step 2 till step 1 is over.

Comment: Block your reactive code is bad idea, because you lose advantage of reactive approach, better way combine your code to one chain and return Mono of MissingCountResult

Answer (score 0):

The point of using reactive programming is to make code async not blocking.
Yes you can block the step1 to finish by not using subscribe but using .block() but this is not the point of reactive programming
if you want to keep it reactive you better return a stream